# Set Definition by Notation: If solutions of $x_j=1$ and $y_j=0$, j is element of set A. Is it correct to use:$A= \{ \forall j:x_j=1, y_j=0 \}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

I would like to specify a set as follows:

If solutions of $x_j=1$ and $y_j=0$, j is element of set A. Is it correct to use the following notation?

$$A= \{ \forall j:x_j=1, y_j=0 \}$$

Comment: It should be $A= \{j:x_j=1, y_j=0 \}$

Comment: The basic Setbuilder notation is $\{x : P(x)\}$, where $x$ is a variable, and $P(x)$ is some logical condition on $x$. The notation means "the set of all $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true" (note that it does not mean that such a set exists - that must be proven separately). Two widely used variations are $\{ x \in S : P(x)\}$ to mean $\{x : x \in S \text{ and } P(x)\}$ and $\{f(t) : P(t)\}$ where $f$ is some functional expression in $t$, to mean $\{x : \exists t, x = f(t)\text{ and }P(t)\}$. There is no version that puts quantifiers on the main variable.